# dealing with exponentials in python - infinities and overflows

Tags: regression, exponential-distribution, boosting, logarithm, function

In a machine learning algorithm that I'm using, I need to get the exponential values of something in one of the steps.

This is the step that I'm dealing with right now:
[image]

I've already got all the 1+g_j(X_i) etc etc calculated, there's no problem in that. Let's call it `calculated_value`. That's fine.

The problem is, I am getting infinities and overflows when implementing this function in code.

What's the solution for this? What would the logarithmic version of the same function, that I could use in place of the function above?

In case it matters, β is going to be used as a coefficient to some variables, including partially to calculate the weights for a weighted regression solution.

Comment: A very good approximation for $\ln(1+\exp(x))$ for $x>7$ or so is $x+\exp(-x)$. This means you can readily take logs of numerator and denominator and work on log-scales when dealing with large arguments.

Answer (score 1):

One way to handle this would be to rescale the terms in the numerator and denominator by a suitably large constant $C$, which is equivalent to subtracting $log(C)$ from the numerator of each exponential terms as follows.  I'll reduce the notation of the problem for simplicity.

$\beta_j(X_i) = \frac{e^A}{1 + e^A + e^B}= \frac{ C^{-1}e^A}{C^{-1} + C^{-1}e^A + C^{-1}e^B} = \frac{ e^{A-log(C)}}{C^{-1} + e^{A-log(C)} + e^{B-log(C)}}$

One possible choice would be to let $log(C) = max(A,B)$.  Then at least you are guaranteed to not have overflow!

Comment: Is the formula that you're proposing a kind of "normalization"? (I'm still learning here..)

Comment: In fact, even the function I asked about above, that too is a kind of normalization, right?

Comment: Sure, you could call it that.  The function you asked about is itself a normalization, but the normalization fails if any one of the exp(x) is inf!